# Error al instalar node con nvm por espacios en directorio

Tags: nodejs, windows, npm, nvm

al tratar de seleccionar la última versión de node usando nvm me da error

```
C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C>nvm use 12.6.0
```

> exit status 1: "C:\Users\Ivana" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Asegúrate de ejecutar tu consola como administrador ya que con esos permisos se instalo.

Comment: Debes ejecutar la `consola` (cmd) en **modo administrador**. Así logré solucionar el problema.

Comment: Me pasó lo mismo, solucione instalando nvm en un directorio que no tenga espacios en el nombre y listo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi solución fue cambiar la ruta de instalación a una carpeta sin espacios

```
nvm root "C:/ambiente/node"
```

Adicionalmente debí mover algunos archivos extras para que funcionara porque me daba este error:

```
C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C>nvm use 12.6.0
```

> exec: "C:\ambiente\node\elevate.cmd": file does not exist:

si tienes problemas ara hallar la ruta de instalación de nvm o no lo recuerdas usa el comando

```
where nvm
```

el contenido de la carpeta deberá quedar así para que funcione:

```
C:\ambiente\node>dir /w
 El volumen de la unidad C es Windows
 El número de serie del volumen es: 1AFD-E68B

 Directorio de C:\ambiente\node

[.]           [..]          elevate.cmd   elevate.vbs   install.cmd   [v12.6.0]
               3 archivos            925 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Una respuesta sencilla en la que no es necesario mover carpetas:

Instalé nvm y la versión de Node que utilizaría para un proyecto, pero tenía un error acceso denegado. Abrí nuevamente la terminal como administrador instalé otra versión de prueba:

```
nvm install v16.13.1 
nvm use 16.13.1
```

y problema resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso la solución fue utilizar la consola de Poweshel con privilegios de administrador.

[Esa fue la solución que se comentó en el issue abierto de nvm.](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/1014#issuecomment-1713258426)

```
 nvm use 16.20.2
 Now using node v16.20.2 (64-bit)
```